# How can I add an item from a switch case exclusively if it is contained in a List

Tags: c#, winforms

Items on the List change dynamically.

Items added to combobox on two conditions:

1. They are contained in **suitable** list
2. They pass the switch case conditions

   ```
   List<string> suitable = new List<string>() { "ASTM", "A216/DIN", "A351/DIN", "A395/DIN", "DIN123" };

   string material = comboBox10.SelectedItem.ToString();

        switch (material)
        {
            case "PN16":
            case "PN25":
            case "CL150":
            //Add only if item in the LIST suitable:
                comboBox25.Items.Clear();
                comboBox25.Items.Add("ASTM A216/DIN"); //NOT Add
                comboBox25.Items.Add("DIN 1.0619"); //NOT Add
                comboBox25.Items.Add("A216/DIN"); //ADD

                break;
            case "PN40":
            case "PN63":
            case "PN100":
            case "CL300":
            case "CL600":
                //Add only If in the List
                comboBox25.Items.Clear();

                comboBox25.Items.Add("DIN 1.0619"); //NOT ADD
                comboBox25.Items.Add("A351/DIN"); //add
                comboBox25.Items.Add("A216/DIN"); //add
                comboBox25.Items.Add("ASTM"); //add

                break;
        }
        comboBox25.SelectedIndex = 0;
   ```

Comment: Can you further specify what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Test if they are in the list with contains : if(combox25.Contains("DIN 1.0619")

Comment: What I'd like to achieve is already commented on the code . Take for example a case where material in 'PN16' , the ONLY item to be added to comboBox25 is "A216/DIN" because it's the only matching item inside SUITABLE list.

Comment: You'd make your life easier with a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before adding just check if the item is within `suitable`, e.g. by using `Contains`:

```
List<string> suitable = new List<string>() { "ASTM", "A216/DIN", "A351/DIN", "A395/DIN", "DIN123" };

string material = comboBox10.SelectedItem.ToString();

switch (material)
{
    case "PN16":
    case "PN25":
    case "CL150":
    //Add only if item in the LIST suitable:
        comboBox25.Items.Clear();
        var candidates = new[] { "ASTM A216/DIN", "DIN 1.0619", "A216/DIN"};
        foreach(var c in candidates)
            if(suitable.Contains(c)) 
                comboBox25.Items.Add(c);
        break;
    case "PN40":
    case "PN63":
    case "PN100":
    case "CL300":
    case "CL600":
        //Add only If in the List
        comboBox25.Items.Clear();
        var candidates = new[] { "DIN 1.0619", "A351/DIN", "A216/DIN", "ASTM"};
        foreach(var c in candidates)
            if(suitable.Contains(c)) 
                comboBox25.Items.Add(c);
        break;
}
comboBox25.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

or with LINQ:

```
foreach(var c in candidates.Where(x => suitable.Contains(x))
    comboBox25.Items.Add(c);
```